# Reading a line of integers from user - Java

Tags: java, tree

This program should take a line from the user, such as "1 2 5 8 3", and use that to build a tree. Having trouble separating out each number as an integer. Read input using `scanner.next()`, tried using a string split, and then parsing each string into an integer. But I check the tree and it's empty. Any thoughts on what is going wrong?

```
System.out.println("Please enter the inital values. Press enter when done.");
String input = scan.next(); // gets the entire line
String[] values = input.split(" "); // split by spaces
int[] intVals = new int[values.length]; //array to store integers
//string to int and stores in integer value array
for (int i = 0; i < values.length; i++) {
    intVals[i] = Integer.parseInt(values[i]);
}
//goes through integers and adds them to tree
for (int j = 0; j < intVals.length; j++) {
    oak.add(j);
}
```

Comment: Hint: simply use System.out.println() to print out the contents of a variable after you computed it. Makes debugging things much easier ... besides: imho ... forgot about all these tailing // comments in your code. The code says what it is doing; no need to repeat that in a comment!

Comment: `scan.next(); // gets the entire line` ... have you check the JavaDoc for that? Doesn't seem so :(.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're trying to read input like *"1 2 5 8 3"*, then use this instead:

```
System.out.println("Please enter the inital values. Press enter when done.");
final String line = scan.nextLine();
final Scanner lineScanner = new Scanner(line);
while(lineScanner.hasNextInt()) {
    oak.add(lineScanner.nextInt());
}
```

It first reads the whole line and then creates a separate `Scanner` to parse it. This is a better approach (in my opinion), than your current one, because it avoids the necessity of splitting a string into an array and converting the items manually to integer. The scanner will do that for you.

With this being said, now about your current problems:

> ```
> scan.next(); // gets the entire line
> ```

This is not true. This just read *one* token, so "everything" until the next delimiter, usually a whitespace. So doing `input.split(" "); // split by spaces` isn't really helpful here.

> ```
> oak.add(j);
> ```

This adds your loop counter to `oak`, not a value from your array `intVals`. But the good thing is, this doesn't matter anymore.

Comment: That works, but the program then will keep looking for more integers after the user hits enter, only stopping when they enter something that isn't an integer. I'd like it to move on to the next line of code after the first enter.

Comment: I've updated it, so it will first read the whole line and then parse it. It won't expect more than one line from the user and won't block your program.